# SyntaxError: invalid label

Tags: jquery, ajax

Hello It took hours now and I don't have a clue whats going on here. I always get the following error, when i send the ajax request with jquery 1.8:

> "SyntaxError: invalid label"

This is my code...

```
        $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#create-workspace-button").click(function () {
        show_dialog($(this));
    })
    $("#submit-create-workspace").live("click", function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        category= $("#id_workspace_category").val();
        workspace_name=$("#id_workspace_name").val()
        var json_data = JSON.stringify({
            "cat":category,
            "workspace_name":workspace_name

        })
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRFToken': $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()

            }
        })
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            data:json_data,
            url: '/workspace/create/',
            success: function(data) {
                alert('hi')



            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                //here a label error happens...i dont know why
                console.log(errorThrown)
            }
        })


    });




    $("#close").click(function () {
        close_dialog($(this));
    })



    function close_dialog(thiz){
        $(thiz).fadeOut(function(){
            $('#layer,.form-submit-dialogbox').fadeOut();
        })
    }
    function show_dialog(thiz){

        $('#layer,.form-submit-dialogbox, #close').fadeIn();
    }
})
```

edit "JSON.stringify(" was missed out...but same error

Comment: Likely unrelated, I'm opposed to your reliance on semicolon insertion. And why is json_data's value in parens?

Comment: Is this a direct cut-and-paste of your code?  The error might be caused by a missing brace, but I don't see that problem in this code.

Comment: @RichieHindle yeah it is...im checking for braces though...thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the ajax part looks like this it works...

```
    $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url :  '/workspace/create/',
            async: false,
            dataType : 'json',
            cache:false,
            data: {
                cat:category,
                workspace_name:workspace_name
            },
            success : function(data){
            //alert(data[0].title);


            },
            error: function(){
                console.log('problems with data transfer');
            }


        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking about a syntax error or a reference error?  You've edited the code but not the title...

Your reference error could be because you're referring to the global `console` object, which in some browsers only exists when the console is open.

Your syntax error could be because of the extra closing parenthesis `)` at the very end of your code, but without seeing the wider context it's hard to tell.

Comment: hi thanx for your answer...its a label error...sorry for the confusion!...the console.log doesn't change the error...with alert its the same...